# Suppose $S_1 =\{ u_1 , u_2 \}$ and $S_2 = \{ v_1 , v_2 \}$ are each independent sets of vectors in an $n$-dimensional vector space $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vectors

Let us assume that every vector in $S_2$ is a linear combination of vectors in $S_1$.

Question: Does that mean that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are bases for the same subspace of $V$?

I know that the answer to this question is yes, the subspace spanned by both $S_1$ and $S_2$ are the same, but how do i show that?

Comment: Your assumption is equivalent to say that the span of $S_1$ contains $S_2$..

Comment: It's worse than an ordinary duplicate, it's the same question asked by the same account. Did you accidentally post twice? Just delete this copy of the question, since the other copy has an accepted answer.

Comment: I did accidentally post it twice, sorry. I tried to delete it but i cant since it has an answer on it. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\dim S_1 = \dim S_2 = 2$ and $S_1 \subset S_2$, then you have $S_1 = S_2$.

To see this, suppose  $ \{ u_1,u_2\}$ is a basis of $S_1$.
If $S_1 \neq S_2$ then there exists $u_3 \in S_2 \setminus S_1$, and the
collection $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$ is linearly independent (otherwise $u_3 \in S_1$). Hence $\dim S_2 \ge 3$, a contradiction.